# Make ComboBox Edit Active When View Is Opened

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a view that opens up on a button click. The view has a combo box that the user is requesting that when the view opens, the combo box is already selected so they don't have to click on it. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean making that combobox focused when the view is initially loaded? Or do you mean set its initial state as `Checked`??

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you would like to have an initial value selected in the ComboBox when you load the view? If you defined your ComboBox with static content, meaning the ComboBox's ItemSource property isn't bound to an object that was constructed using the results of a database query, you could set the IsSelected property of the ComboBoxItem you want selected to true. For example:

If I want to have the apples initially selected in the example below, I could do the following:

```
<ComboBox Name="fruits" >
   <ComboBoxItem Content="apples" IsSelected="true"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="pears"/>
   <ComboBoxItem Content="oranges"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: My combo box is grabbing a default list from a dataset. What the user is asking for is when the dialog is opened, a blinking "|" is in the box, just like when it's clicked on to edit. Is there a way to do this?